# Solve linear first order differential equation with heavy side function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, discrete-mathematics

I have a differential equation of the form

```
dy/dx + p(x) y = q(x)
```

under the condition that `q(x) = 300` if `y < 3312` and `q(x) = 0` if `y >= 3312`

I could not understand how to solve this differential equation with such heavy side function ?

Any hints ?

Comment: what is $p(x)?$

Comment: p(x) = 1 / (20 + (x/2))

Answer (score 1):

Solve this equation on two domains separately: on $(-\infty,3312)$ and on $(3312,+\infty)$, then use the arbitrary constant that you obtained in both cases to make $y$ globally continuous.

Comment: I did not understand. Can you please elaborate with some equation .. ?

Comment: you mean make $y$ continuous at the boundary $x = 3312.$

Answer (score 0):

so you have the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{2}{40 + x} y= k $$ multiplying by $(40+x)^2$ we get $$k(40+x)^2 = (40+x)^2\frac{dy}{dx} + 2(40 + x) y =
\frac{d}{dx} \left( (40+x)^2y\right) =  $$ this gives $$y =\frac k 3(40 + x) +\frac C{(40+x)^2}.$$

for your problem we have $$ y = 100(40+x) + \frac{C}{(40+x)^2}\text{ for } x \le 3312 \\y = \frac{D}{(40+x)^2}\text{ for } x \ge 3312$$ the matching condition is 
$$ 100(40+3312) + \frac{C}{(40+3312)^2} = \frac{D}{(40+3312)^2}$$